# Using a DSL modem to increase the number of LAN ports causes losing Internet access

Tags: windows-7, networking, ip, lan

An old idle DSL modem/router with 3 LAN (RJ45) ports and one WAN/LAN port was used to extend network outlets in a room with wall LAN outlet shortage and to share a printer among other PCs of the network as well.

Works done:

1. The DSL modem/router was reset to default settings.
2. The DSL modem/router's IP was set to 192.168.1.24 to avoid IP
   conflict with actual DSL modem/router with IP address 192.168.1.1
   which provides internet access to the entire network.
3. The wall LAN outlet which is supposed to be extended, was connected
   directly to the DSL modem/router on port LAN1.
4. A PC was connected to the DSL modem/router on port LAN2.
5. A printer with LAN port was connected to the DSL modem/router on
   port LAN3.
6. Port WAN/LAN was left unused.

The problem is that just the printer is shared and internet access to the PC is lost.

Any mistake with my Hardware (Cables, port ordering,...) or Software configurations (IPs, sharing permissions,...)???

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the PC get assigned a proper IP address? Does it get the correct default route? Can it reach the router(s)?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by default route?

Comment: The default route is sometimes called the gateway. It's the IP address that the device forwards packets to non-local addresses to. In Windows, the `ipconfig` command will tell you.

Comment: As per the answer by @DavidSchwartz, you are having conflicting IP address being handed out and need to turn off the DHCP on the router(s) not connected to the wall.  This basically turns all subsequent routers into switches.  The router plugged into the wall is the only one handing out IP address.  As for connecting the USB printer to the USB port on the router their are a couple of POTENTIAL problems.  In order to access the usb port of the router you MAY need to be connected to that particular router.  The router with the shared USB port may NEED to be the router handing out the IP address.

Comment: And to go another step further, just because you have a USB port on your router does not mean it is setup to handle USB printers.  It could be set up for only dealing with USB storage.  Sharing a portable HDD with the network.  I leave this a  comment as they are possibilities that hopefully someone with more knowledge can clarify.

Comment: @ForwardEd The modem/router has some options in USB section:  
https://www.manualslib.com/manual/444166/Tp-Link-Td-W8970.html?page=65#manual  
and  
https://www.manualslib.com/manual/444166/Tp-Link-Td-W8970.html?page=72#manual  
Doesn't it mean that it supports USB printer?

Comment: @user1051305 It appears from the linked documentation that you have the option to configure/select the USB port to behave as a print server.  You MIGHT still need to install printer drivers on individual machines to actually print but it should not stop you from seeing the printer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you forgot to disable DHCP in the modem/router. This causes the PC to get the wrong default gateway, making it unable to reach the Internet.

If the modem/router has no specific way to disable its DHCP server, see if it has a way to be put in bridge mode. This will usually disable the DHCP server.

Comment: Man, it was the trick. Thank you. Now, the PC has both the printer and Internet access.

Comment: Sir, I need to share another Printer this time it's a USB printer. I walked through the steps for previous problem, but this time I have only Internet. I can't even reach the modem panel through its IP (192.168.1.25) and subsequently can't access the second printer (the USB one). Any help this time too. Thanks a million.

Comment: @user1051305 What are you trying to connect the USB printer to? A PC?

Comment: No sir. Actually the USB printer should be shared between two PCs in a room regardless of the PCs are on or off. Also it's not bad if the USB printer is shared among any other PCs in the network.

Comment: Right, but what will it connect to?

Comment: The USB printer should be connected to a TP-Link DSL modem/router (having four RJ45 ports and one female USB port) via the USB port. Again, the modem itself is connected to both Internet (wall outlet) and directly the first PC using RJ45 ports. And once again the first PC is going to have both Internet and the USB printer, yet the second PC and (why not!) other PCs in the LAN can have both of them too.

Comment: @user1051305 I doubt the modem/router supports that. But if you tell me exactly what model of modem/router and what model of printer, I can probably check. You're probably better off connecting the printer to a PC and sharing it from there.

Comment: The USB printer is an HP LaserJet P2055 and the modem/router is a TP-Link TD-W8970.